# How to use pool.starmap() on pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

Taking the second answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments), I have tried the following code

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
from itertools import repeat
import pandas as pd

def doubler(number, r):
    result = number * 2 + r
    return result

def f1():
    return np.random.randint(20)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30,40,50,60], "B": [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6]})
    num_chunks = 3
    # break df into 3 chunks
    chunks_dict = {i:np.array_split(df, num_chunks)[i] for i in range(num_chunks)}

    arg1 = f1()

    with Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(doubler, [zip(chunks_dict[i]['B'], repeat(arg1)) for i in range(num_chunks)])

    print(results)

>>> [(-1, 20, -1, 20, -2, 20), (-3, 20, -3, 20, -4, 20), (-5, 20, -5, 20, -6, 20)]
```

This is not the results I want. What I want is to feed each element of column `B` of `df` into the `doubler` function, as well as the output from `f1` - this is why I am using `starmap` and `repeat` - to get a list output of the input doubled and some random integer added to it.

For example, if the output of `f1` was 2, then I want to return

```
>>> [0,-2,-4,-6,-8,-10] # [2*(-1) + 2, 2*(-2) + 2, ... ]
```

Can anyone advise how I would achieve this desired result? Thanks

EDIT: Inserting the whole data frame does not work either:

```
with Pool() as pool:
    results = pool.starmap(doubler, [zip(df['B'], repeat(arg1))])

>>> TypeError: doubler() takes 2 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

Essentially, I just want to break up my dataframe into chunks, and give these chunks, as well as other variables (arg1) into a function that accepts more than one argument.

Comment: I think your `f1()` should be returning that random number, right? I don't think that solves your problem but that looks odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your arguments don't look right. For instance, after adding a `print` of the arguments in `doubler` I see the following (assume `f1()` returns `2`):

```
doubler number (-3, 2) r (-4, 2)
doubler number (-1, 2) r (-2, 2)
doubler number (-5, 2) r (-6, 2)
```

This is because the arguments passed into the `starmap` are `zipped` together as opposed to just a list of `tuples`.

I think it is much easier to rewrite your chunking procedure and argument generation. Assuming I'm understanding this correctly, you want to result in the following tuple list for the arguments (assume `f1()` returns `2`):

[(-1, 2), (-2, 2), (-3, 2), (-4, 2), (-5, 2), (-6, 2)]

This will then get applied to the `doubler` function such that the `starmap` returns this `[doubler(-1, 2), doubler(-2, 2),...doubler(-6, 2)]` which is `[[0, -2, -4, -6, -8, -10]`.  Try this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
from itertools import repeat
import pandas as pd


def doubler(number, r):
    result = number * 2 + r
    return result


def f1():
    return np.random.randint(20)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60], "B": [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6]})
    num_processes = 3

    # the "r" value to use with every "B" value
    random_r = f1()

    # zip together a list of tuples of each B value and the random r value
    tuples = [(b, r) for b, r in zip(df.B.values, repeat(random_r, len(df.B.values)))]
    print(tuples)

    with Pool(num_processes) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(doubler, tuples)

    print(results)
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work for this simple case. Is there any way to check if each processing core is only working on a single chunk of the data? What I mean by that is, if I run some code operating on 300k rows of a dataframe in serial, it takes 30 minutes - therefore I would expect that splitting the data into 4 chunks and having 1 core work on 1 chunk (75k rows) I would expect the time to be quartered i.e. to about 7-8 minutes. However this isnt happening, it takes the same amount of time as the serial code.